# Should a reference to an enum be dereferenced before it is matched?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, dereference

As a newcomer to Rust, I've stumbled upon two apparently valid ways of running a `match` on a reference type.

I've defined an enum:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Teal,
    Blue,
    Purple,
}
```

I want to implement a function that works on a `&self` reference of an instance of this enum.

I can see two ways to write such a function:

```
impl Color {
    // Approach #1: Match the reference, using references in each pattern
    fn contains_red(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            &Color::Red => true,
            &Color::Yellow => true,
            &Color::Purple => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }

    // Approach #2: Dereference &self and match the patterns directly
    fn contains_blue(&self) -> bool {
        match *self {
            Color::Blue => true,
            Color::Teal => true,
            Color::Purple => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that dereferencing `&self` would be counted as a move, and would cause errors if I called `color.contains_blue()` on the same instance twice in a row, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Are these approaches functionally identical? Would one of them break down if I were matching more complex objects?

Comment: I've been told to dereference the match argument (your approach #2) as it's more idiomatic because it has less clutter. I hope someone can chime in with a more authoritative answer. :-)

Comment: Just to make sure: `Color` is not `Copy`, right?

Comment: @Matthieu Nope, it's defined as seen above, with no attributes. But if that makes a significant difference as to the behavior, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Yep, I'm also pretty sure that the second approach is the idiomatic one, but I can't give any links supporting this claim as well :) And whether the matched value is `Copy` or not also does not make difference, I believe.

Comment: @Shepmaster Is the style guide authoritative enough? https://doc.rust-lang.org/style/features/match.html (OK, not quite the same, but still ...)

Comment: @starblue I think that would be a fine answer. It's at least an opinion that comes from the creators of Rust, who ought to know how to use their language. I'd still love to know if there's a real functional difference between the two approaches, however, or if it really is just a style thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't move out of an immutable reference, so you don't have to worry about that being the case.

It's worth considering that one would expect matches to work *somewhat* akin to (`Partial`)`Eq`, and that takes `&self`. In other words, one would expect it to take a reference implicitly unless forced. This is easily confirmed with a little experimentation.

It's worth noting that `*self` is *not* a move - it's a reference to a memory location. [It is thus an lvalue.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#lvalues-rvalues-and-temporaries) Ergo,

> When the head expression is an lvalue, the match does not allocate a temporary location (however, a by-value binding may copy or move from the lvalue).

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/match-expr.html

If a temporary location is not allocated, a move cannot occur. Thus the behaviour is guaranteed. As the parenthetical notes, internal data can still get moved out from destructuring pattern, which would cause a problem. This, however, is true regardless of whether you are matching on `self` or `*self`.

Using `*self` seems to be an informal idiom, and should be preferred.

Comment: That helps clear things up a lot. Knowing that a move cannot occur when using something as an lvalue makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust 1.26, the idiomatic solution is *neither*; you don't have to dereference the value *or* add `&` to the patterns:

```
fn contains_blue(&self) -> bool {
    match self {
        Color::Blue => true,
        Color::Teal => true,
        Color::Purple => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

This is thanks to improved match ergonomics.

You can also use pattern alternation in this case:

```
match self {
    Color::Blue | Color::Teal | Color::Purple => true,
    _ => false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the second. It conveys the intent better, in my opinion.