# How does the match expression interpret values vs. references?

Tags: reference, rust, match

In this example, why can I dereference `t` in the match expression but not on the line directly above?

```
fn tree_weight_v2(t: &BinaryTree) -> i32 {
    // let x = *t; // if uncommented, error: "Cannot move out of borrowed content"
    match *t {
        BinaryTree::Leaf(payload) => payload,
        BinaryTree::Node(ref left, payload, ref right) => {
            tree_weight_v2(left) + payload + tree_weight_v2(right)
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn tree_demo_2() {
    let tree = sample_tree();
    assert_eq!(tree_weight_v2(&tree), (1 + 2 + 3) + 4 + 5);
    assert_eq!(tree_weight_v2(&tree), (1 + 2 + 3) + 4 + 5);
    // no error ^ meaning tree_weight_v2 is not taking ownership of tree
}

enum BinaryTree {
    Leaf(i32),
    Node(Box<BinaryTree>, i32, Box<BinaryTree>)
}

fn sample_tree() -> BinaryTree {
    let l1 = Box::new(BinaryTree::Leaf(1));
    let l3 = Box::new(BinaryTree::Leaf(3));
    let n2 = Box::new(BinaryTree::Node(l1, 2, l3));
    let l5 = Box::new(BinaryTree::Leaf(5));

    BinaryTree::Node(n2, 4, l5)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0925329a6bc346730e8bb877fc60c8be&version=stable&mode=debug)

I don't believe what the code is doing beyond the match statement to be important - unless of course, that is the source of my confusion.

I'm also curious about how match expressions handle dereferenced values. Specifically, since what the match expression sees is a value of type `BinaryTree` (without any references), why does the match expression not try to take ownership over it? More generally, how does Rust's `match` interpret the difference between a dereferenced pointer to a value and a normal value?

Comment: You're trying to move a borrowed value which isn't allowed by the borrowchecker. `match` just borrows the value (which is valid; you can borrow from a borrow). That would be equivalent to `let x = &*t` instead of `let x = *t`.

Comment: Also fun fact: as of Rust 1.26 you don't need to dereference in a `match` anymore (though you may choose to for people using older Rust versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let x = *t` does not work, because it's moved out of the reference. I.e. this means, with dereferencing `t`, you get a `BinaryTree` (without reference). The `BinaryTree` is borrowed in the function, so assigning it with `let x = *t` will move the it into the x, which is not possible, since it's borrowed.

The match does work, because `match` borrows the variable. `match *t` will not move it out, but it will borrow the `BinaryTree`. This is a special syntax in Rust and the borrow happens behind the scenes. You can think of this:

```
fn tree_weight_v2(t: &BinaryTree) -> i32 {
    match &*t {
        &BinaryTree::Leaf(payload) => payload,
        &BinaryTree::Node(ref left, payload, ref right) => {
            tree_weight_v2(left) + payload + tree_weight_v2(right)
        }
    }
}
```

but all the references are not needed.

---

See also:

- [Is there any difference between matching on a reference to a pattern or a dereferenced value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054)
- [Should a reference to an enum be dereferenced before it is matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35921015)